# How to Implement Individual Accounts without Registration in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm wanting to test ASP.NET MVC for a new project. One of the requirements is not allowing users to register themselves. When I select individual accounts in the MVC project type, it does not allow for the elimination of the registration option.

Is it possible to create an individual account project without the user registration portion? Do I need to roll my own custom classes? If so, what? I've looked for similar answers, but cannot find any without an already deep discussion and assumption that I am already familiar with libraries involved.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Would simply hiding/disabling the user registration pages suffice?  Remove the various links to the pages and throw a not implemented exception at the top of the controller actions in question.

Comment: That seems more of a hackish workaround. I had the same idea, but thought there is certainly a better way.